# How to convert this function into a Common Lisp macro that has a variable number of cond clauses?

Tags: if-statement, macros, conditional-statements, common-lisp, variadic-functions

I am using Emacs, Slime, and SBCL. Simplifying a problem that I am facing, suppose I have this function working:

```lisp
(defun get-answer (x y z)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be: ~s ~s ~s ~%" x y z)
  (let ((answer  (read-line)))
    (cond ((equal answer x) (format t "user picks ~s" x))
          ((equal answer y) (format t "user picks ~s" y))
          ((equal answer z) (format t "user picks ~s" z)))))
```

It works for a fixed number of inputs:

```lisp
CL-USER> (get-answer "fish" "cat" "owl")
Which animal would you like to be: "fish" "cat" "owl" 
fish
user picks "fish"
NIL
```

I would like to generalize this function **writing a variant argument macro** that builds a **variant number** of `cond` clauses. Basically, Common Lisp macro would write the cond clause for me :)

For instance, I wish I could call it like:

```lisp
CL-USER> (get-answer '("pig" "zebra" "lion" "dog" "cat" "shark"))
```

Or just:

```lisp
CL-USER> (get-answer '("dog" "cat"))
```

Either way, it would generate 6 and 2 appropriate `cond` clauses, respectively. I tried building something to achieve this goal.

My draft/sketch focusing on the `cond` clause part is:

```lisp
(defmacro macro-get-answer (args)
  `(cond
     (,@(mapcar (lambda (str+body)
                  (let ((str (first str+body))
                        (body (second str+body)))
                    `((string= answer ,str)
                      ,body)))
                args))))
```

The variable `answer` was supposed to hold the value inserted by the user. However, I can't manage to make it work. `slime-macroexpand-1` is not being really helpful.

As an error message, I get:

```lisp
The value
  QUOTE
is not of type
  LIST
```

Which is not something that I was expecting. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, macros don't evaluate their arguments in CL; there is no need to quote a list argument when passing it to a macro. But I think that there are other problems here, e.g., why do you want a macro for this instead of a simple function?

Comment: why do you need conditions, when all do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a macro. Note that there's a repeating pattern of `((equal answer x) (format t "user picks ~s" x))`, so you should think how to simplify that.

So, this is your function and expected inputs:

```
(defun get-answer (x y z)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be: ~s ~s ~s ~%" x y z)
  (let ((answer  (read-line)))
    (cond ((equal answer x) (format t "user picks ~s" x))
          ((equal answer y) (format t "user picks ~s" y))
          ((equal answer z) (format t "user picks ~s" z)))))

(get-answer '("pig" "zebra" "lion" "dog" "cat" "shark"))
(get-answer '("dog" "cat"))
```

I'd write something like this:

```
(defun get-answer (args)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be: ~{~s ~} ~%" args)
  (let ((answer (read-line)))
    (when (member answer args :test #'string=)
      (format t "User picks ~s" answer)
      answer)))
```

Tests:

```
(get-answer '("pig" "zebra" "lion" "dog" "cat" "shark"))
(get-answer '("dog" "cat"))
```

Note that your function always returned `NIL`, mine returns chosen string or `NIL`. After you recieve user input, you probably don't want to discard it immediately.

And if you have string with values, like this:

```
(get-answer '(("pig" 1) ("zebra" 3) ("lion" 2) ("dog" 8) ("cat" 12) ("shark" 20)))
```

I'd use [`find`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm):

```
(defun get-answer (args)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be: ~{~s ~} ~%" (mapcar #'first args))
  (let* ((answer (read-line))
         (match (find answer args :test #'string= :key #'car)))
    (when match 
      (format t "User picks ~s " (first match))
      (second match))))
```

This function returns `NIL` or value of chosen animal.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little bit strange, but maybe the point is just to learn about *Common Lisp*'s macros. One could just calculate the members of the condition in a first place. That means, generate a list of `string=` forms. Then just return a list containing the `cond` special form and the list of `((string= str) return-value)`.

```
(defmacro get-answer (answers)
  (let ((clauses (mapcar (lambda (str+body)
                           (let ((str  (first str+body))
                                 (body (second str+body)))
                             `((string= ,str) ,body))) answers)))
    `(cond ,@clauses)))
```

To test macros, one can use [macroexpand](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) and [macroexpand-1](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm).

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(get-answer (("test1" 1) ("test2" 2))))
(COND
  ((STRING= "test1") 1) 
  ((STRING= "test2") 2))
```

---

But I don't personally think it is worth a macro. I think there is nothing wrong with the following function:

```
(defun get-answer (answer)
  (cond
    ((string= answer "dog") 6)
    ((string= answer "cat") 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

As with [Martin Půda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72008787/17026934): this is not a good place where you need a macro.  In particular if you want some undetermined number of options, pass a list of them: Common Lisp has extremely good list-handling functions.

In the simple case you give, the function becomes almost trivial:

```
(defun get-answer (options)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be (from ~{~A~^, ~})? " options)
  (let ((selected (car (member (read-line) options :test #'string-equal))))
    (format t "picked ~S~%" (or selected "(a bad answer)"))
    selected))
```

If what you want to to is to map a value selected by the user to another value, then what you want is an alist or a plist:

```
(defun get-answer/map (option-map)
  (format t "Which animal would you like to be (from ~{~A~^, ~})? "
          (mapcar #'car option-map))
  (let ((selected (assoc (read-line) option-map :test #'string-equal)))
    (format t "picked ~A~%" (if selected (car selected) "(a bad value)"))
    ;; Second value tells us if fn succeeded, as first can be NIL
    (values (cdr selected) selected)))
```

The *whole purpose* of functions like `member` and `assoc` is to search for entries in lists: there is no use in laboriously reimplementing half-working versions of them by writing lots of `cond` clauses, whether or not you do this automatically.

---

Now, people often say 'but I want to learn macros, so I will start by learning how to rewrite functions as macros'.  *That is a not where to start*: macros are *never* useful for rewriting functions in this way, and thinking they are is very damaging.

Here's one simple example of a case where this can't work:

```
(get-answer (read-options-from-file *my-options-file*))
```

If `get-answer` were a macro how is this meant to work?  The number of options is not only unknown at macroexpansion time, it is not even *knowable*, even in principle, because neither the file's name nor its contents can possibly be known at compile time.

Macros are not replacements for functions: they are are *functions between languages*: a macro compiles a language which is CL (+ other macros) + the language understood by the macro into a language which is CL (+ other macros).

I am slightly struggling to think of a case where a macro might be useful here, but perhaps we can imagine a language which has a `with-answer-options` form:

```
(with-answer-options (a)
  ("elephant" (explode-world :because-of a))
  ("fish" (set-fire-to-computer :blaming a)))
```

Note that this form now looks nothing like a function call: it is instead a little language which slightly extends CL, and which will get mapped to CL by the following macro:

```
(defmacro with-answer-options ((var &optional (prompt "Pick an answer"))
                               &body clauses)
  (unless (symbolp var)
    (error "~S should be a variable" var))
  (let ((choices (mapcar #'car clauses)))
    (unless (every #'stringp choices)
      (error "choices should be (<literal string> form ...)"))
    `(let ((,var (progn (format t "~A from ~{~A~^ ~}? "
                                ,prompt ',choices)
                   (read-line))))
       (cond
        ,@(mapcar (lambda (clause)
                    (destructuring-bind (val &body body) clause
                      `((string-equal ,var ',val)
                        ,@body)))
                  clauses)
        (t (error "~A is not one of ~{~A~^ ~}" ,var ',choices))))))
```

So now:

```
> (with-answer-options (a "Pick a bad thing")
    ("elephant" (explode-world :because-of a))
    ("fish" (set-fire-to-computer :blaming a)))
Pick a bad thing from elephant fish? frog

Error: frog is not one of elephant fish
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a QUOTE, because your macro form contains one:

```
CL-USER 8 > (defmacro macro-get-answer (args) (print args) nil)
MACRO-GET-ANSWER

CL-USER 9 > (macro-get-answer '(1 2 3))

(QUOTE (1 2 3)) 
NIL


CL-USER 10 > (macro-get-answer (quote (1 2 3)))

(QUOTE (1 2 3)) 
NIL
```

Possible solutions:

- don't use a quote
- remove the quote